# Find centre of rotation from two locations

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, vector

[image: representation of problem]

Ultimately I need to get `c` from the image and have `a`, `b` and that it takes 90 degrees to get `a` to `d`.

My solution to this was to rotate a around to get to `d` by the rotation. Then use the Y value from `a` and X from `d` to get `c`.

So far I an having trouble getting the rotation of `a` to `d` to work properly, what am I doing wrong in the rotation?

```
    Vector3 d = (Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation) * (a - b)) + b;
```

Comment: You're code and description seem to match up, but the image definitely does not show `d` as being rotated from `a` 90 degrees around `b`.

Comment: @Jay Looking back on it again I get what you mean, I guess what I'm trying to say is that I'm attempting to get to `d` so that I can work out `c`. How I get  `d` or `c` is that part that i'm stuck on. I'm sure that all the information that i need is there... I just need to piece it together...